# I am not able to render the data in react

Tags: reactjs, express

**Hi, my frontend is not reading JSON data sent by my backend, can you help:
The backend is perfectly generating the JSON. But my react component is not able to consume the API.**

**Frontend**:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  state={
    users:[]
  };



  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('/employees')
      .then(res => {
          return res.json()
       })
      .then(data => {  
          this.setState({ users:data })
       })
       .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);});
   }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        {this.state.users.map(user =>
                <div key={user.id}>user: {user.name} Salary: {user.salary}</div>
              )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

I am trying to fetch data from localhost:9000/employee but it is not reading .

**Backend:**

```
//Step1:    import mongodb module
var mongodb = require("mongodb");

//Step2:    Create client for mongodb
var mongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

//Step3:    Define url with mongodb path
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/Employee";

var app = require("express")();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/employees',function(req,resp){
    mongoClient.connect(url,function(err,db){
        if ( !err){
            var collection = db.collection("lcdEmployees");
            var cursor = collection.find().toArray(function(err,records){
                if ( !err )
                    resp.send(records);
            });
        }
    });
});
app.listen(9000,()=>console.log("API with db access started listening..."));
```

Comment: Your localhost is running in port 9000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just making a request to '/employees' you need to provide the full url to fetch
something like

```
localhost:/9000/employees
```

hope it helps

Comment: Yes I am getting

Comment: have you deployed the API somewhere so i can hit and check ?